# After how much time will the tank be full given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> P and Q are filling pipes which can fill a tank in $15$ minutes and $20$ minutes respectively.R is an emptying pipe which can empty the full tank in $30$ minutes.The $3$ pipes are operated continuously one after the other in the order of P,Q and R,each being kept opened for $2$ minutes. until the tank is full.After how much time will the tank be full?

MyApproach:

$1$/$15$ + $1$/$20$ - $1$/$30$=$5$/$12$

After $2$ minutes,the tank is filled=$5$/$6$

=>$1$/$6$ of the tank will be filled in ?

I can solve unto this equation.

Am i right in my approach?Please give me a HINT to solve the rest part?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

During the first cycle, the tank will be filled $$\frac{2}{15}+\frac{2}{20} - \frac{2}{30} = \frac{20+30-25}{150} = \frac{25}{150} = \frac{1}{6}$$

So then it will take __ cycles. Each cycle takes 2 mins, so it will take __ mins.

Comment: Not got to the solution

Comment: It is filled after 6 cycles. Each cycle takes 2 mins so that's a total of 12 mins.

Comment: @MarkWatson It's actually six minutes per proposed cycle, and you're forgetting that the tank will be full midway through the sixth cycle.

Comment: @egglog this is a blast from the past.

Answer (score 0):

The tanks aren't run at the same time:

Pipe R runs two minutes so the tank is filled 2/15 after 2 minutes.

Pipe Q runs two minutes so the tank is filled 2/15 + 2/20 after 4 minutes

Pipe R runs two minutes so the tank is filled 2/15 + 2/20 -2/30 = 1/6  after 6 minutes.

Repeat this six times and the tank will be full.

Answer (score 0):

Each cycle is 6 mins (2+2+2)

Lets take total volume to be filled as 60L

After 5 cycles of 6 mins each, lets say 50L is filled
30 minutes has elapsed

10L remaining
in 2 minutes: 8L will be filled by first pipe
2L remaining, 32  mins elapsed

the remaining 2L is filled by second pipe at the rate of 3/min, therefore time taken is 2/3 mins

Therefore, final answer is 32 2/3 minutes to fill the tank.

Answer (score 0):

The flow rate for each pipe is:
$p=V/15=V/20=-V/30$, (liters per minute).

In a six-minute cycle, the tank is full for:

$\frac{8V}{60}+\frac{6V}{60}-\frac{4V}{60}=\frac{10V}{60}$.

So to get to fill the tank, it takes 5 full cycles plus a tap opening of pipe A for two minutes, plus even the opening of tap B for 40 seconds.
Altogether we have the total time to fill the tank that is:

$5.6+2+2/3=32' 40''$.